# How to get data from database separated by comma?

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I have created two tables:

**attendance_data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE attendance_data 
(  
  _id integer primary key autoincrement,
  stud_roll text not null,
  sem integer ,
  class_id integer 
);
```

**class_data**

```sql
CREATE TABLE class_data 
( 
  class_id integer primary key autoincrement, 
  course_name text not null, 
  t_id integer, 
  date text 
);
```

I want to fetch the `class_id` from the `class_data` table where the `date` column has the value in `currtime` i.e Mar 24, 2014 1:41:12 AM

But it shows the following error when do the query:

```
03-24 01:41:12.194: I/SHUBH(2245): GETTING Class ID by Mar 24, 2014 1:41:12 AM
03-24 01:41:12.194: I/Database(2245): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "24": syntax error
03-24 01:41:12.214: W/System.err(2245): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "24": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT class_id FROM class_data WHERE date = Mar 24, 2014 1:41:12 AM
03-24 01:41:12.214: W/System.err(2245):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-24 01:41:12.224: W/System.err(2245):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
```

I think it happens because of the comma present in the date. How should I write the query to make it work?

Here's the **getClassID()** method that I have written to fetch the ID:

```java
public String getClassID(String currtime) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String cidddd = "";
    Log.i("SHUBH", "GETTING Class ID by " + currtime);

    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(
                        true, 
                        DATABASE_TABLE5,
                        new String[] { KEY_CLASS_ID }, 
                        " date " + " = " + currtime,
                        null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {

        startManagingCursor(mCursor);

        while (mCursor.moveToNext()) {
            cidddd = mCursor.getString(0);
        }

        System.out.println(cidddd + "This is the class IDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
        mCursor.close();            
    }

    System.out.println("Cursor NuLL");
    return cidddd;
}
```

Comment: You should use a `DateTime` type for your date field, not a `text` type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclosing the text in your `currtime` date string in single quotes will get past the syntax error:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT class_id FROM class_data WHERE date = 'Mar 24, 2014 1:41:12 AM'
```

So, change the 8th line in your `getClassID()` method to this:

```java
" date = '" + currtime + "'",
```

Depending on the format of the date & time in your `date` text column, you may need to use the built-in [**SQLite Date And Time Functions**](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) in order to do the comparison in the same format.